# CSS Auto Margin pushing down other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a site beautiful, and so far it's gone quite well, by problem arose when attempting to center a column with 2 side columns, if I use `margin:0 auto`; the 2 side columns are pushed down beneath the middle centered column, is there a way for them to occupy space beside the central column, even while centered?

Here's my CSS:

```
body {

    background-image: url(../images/background.png);

    background-repeat: repeat;

    background-color: #F0C36B;

    font-family:Arial;

    color:#FFF;

}

#header, #footer {

    text-align:center;

    clear:both;

}

#header {
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    }

#left_column, #right_column, #center_column {

    background-color:#5B7A8C;

    border-radius: 10px;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;

    -icab-border-radius: 10px;

    -o-border-radius: 10px;

    border:solid #FFF 2px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;

    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000000;

} 

#left_column {

    width:20%;

    float:left;

    text-align:center;

}

#right_column {

    width:20%;

    float:right;

    text-align:center;

}

#center_column {

    width:50%;

    padding:0.5em;

    margin:0 auto;

}

#page_container {

    width:90%;

    margin:0 auto;

}

#headline {

    font-family:TF2 Build;

    font-size:2em;

    }

#author {

    font-style: italic;

    font-size:0.7em;

    }

@font-face {

  font-family: "TF2";

  src: url(../fonts/TF2.eot);

  src: local("☺"),

    url("../fonts/TF2.ttf") format("truetype");

}

@font-face {

  font-family: "TF2 Build";

  src: url(../fonts/tf2build.eot);

  src: local("☺"),

    url("../fonts/tf2build.ttf") format("truetype");

}

h2 {

    font-family: "TF2";

    color: #FFF;

    margin:0.25em;

}

hr {

    border: 1px solid #FFF;

}
```

My site resides at http://tf2ware.net

I hope you can help and thanks if anticipation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `#center_column` div after the `#right_column` div.

This isn't the best of all answers as it changes the markup to adjust the style, but it should work for a quick-fix.

Edit to explain: I didn't post a why before, and I think it might be useful.

[docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the **current line**. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be prohibited from doing so by the 'clear' property). Content flows down the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a right-floated box. The following is an introduction to float positioning and content flow; the exact rules governing float behavior are given in the description of the 'float' property.

I bolded the important part. Because the centered div was already in the display list, the current line for `#left_column` and `#right_column` is *after* `#center_column`. Once you put `#center_column` after the left and right columns, the current line is *next to* the floated elements.

Comment: But then the items just appear way over the top of the `#center_column` column div. I want them to appear beside.

Comment: Wait, what? http://tf2ware.net/
That worked perfectly. I tried that!

Well thanks anyway guys, guess I didn't need to ask for your help at all.

Comment: Why is it in this case that the center column has to be written last, but in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713181/elastic-layout-with-max-width-and-min-width-using-grid-based-design/4714558#4714558), the column that's not floated can be written before the float?  Check out the Live Demo link on jsbin.

Comment: Actually, I just posted a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591108/why-does-order-of-float-div-and-non-float-div-matter-only-in-some-cases

Answer (score 1):

```
#page_container { text-align: center; }
#left_column { float: left; }
#right_column { float: right; }
```

and change the order of the dom to make `#center` column last.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want to change the order in your html (for SEO, screenreaders, etc.), you can also use absolute positioning for the side columns, but that might lead to problems if the side columns can have a greater height than the center column.