# Why does order of float div and non-float div matter only in some cases?

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I have a similar problem as [CSS Auto Margin pushing down other elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171571/css-auto-margin-pushing-down-other-elements): A right floating sidebar gets pushed down below the main non-floating content div.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171571/css-auto-margin-pushing-down-other-elements/5171603#5171603) proposed works: just reverse the order of the markup and write out the float div *before* the non-float div.

For example, this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="non-floating-content">
        fooburg content
    </div>
    <div id="float-right">
        test right
    </div>
</div>
```

needs to be awkwardly re-ordered as:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="float-right">
        test right
    </div>
    <div id="non-floating-content">
        fooburg content
    </div>
</div>
```

So then, why does this also work without reordering: [Elastic layout with max-width and min-width using grid based design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713181/elastic-layout-with-max-width-and-min-width-using-grid-based-design/4714558#4714558)? 
Check out the [live demo](http://jsbin.com/ozilo4/edit).  The ordering of the markup is still sensible: the float div is written out *after* the non-float div.  Yet the float doesn't get pushed down on the page.

I ask because I would prefer not to have to hack the theme PHP (to reorder divs) in order to properly style it.

Other posts that also say the solution is to "re-order your divs":

- [2 column div layout: right column with fixed width, left fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195836/2-column-div-layout-right-column-with-fixed-width-left-fluid)
- [Semi Fluid Layout CSS/Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587122/semi-fluid-layout-css-html)

Comment: Its hard to know without seeing the original problem. I would suggest you post a comment on that question's accepted answer?

Comment: Where is the non-floated div in the live demo?

Comment: @kinakuta the non-floated div in the live demo is #fluidColumnContainer

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find the float rules for that. Are you certain? (I could just be blind)

Comment: I updated the [live demo](http://jsbin.com/ozilo4/edit) link.  The CSS rule for #fluidColumnContainer is `#fluidColumnContainer {
  padding: 0 200px 0 0
}`.  That's all.

Comment: nevermind - I was a little confused about the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this works is because your containing element has no height. When you have nothing but floated elements inside a containing element, it will collapse to 0 height. If you were, for example, to add overflow: hidden; to #fluidColumnContainer, it would act as a clear-fix, expanding the container to contain the floated elements. Then you would see the right-floated element drop down again.

Comment: Ah cool, that makes sense; I didn't even notice the collapsed container. Thanks a lot!  Let's see if this new knowledge helps me fix my site...

Answer (score 0):

the reason the one you linked works is because the other columns are also floated

Comment: So you're saying that floating something *inside* the non-float div makes a difference?  Wow.

Comment: @hyuz: that depends on the [block context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work) of elements involved...